# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException and org.hibernate.AnnotationException

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have SIMProvisionedRange table, which have a composite key and unique key,
M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range_Accounts is used to map SIMProvisionedRange and Accounts table.
I am having problem in hibernate mapping for one to many unidirection.

```
@Entity(name = "M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range")
@Table
public class SIMProvisionedRange {

    @Column(unique=true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer SIMProvisionedRangeId;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range_Accounts", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "SIMProvisionedRangeId")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "AccountId")})
    private Set<AdminAccounts> adminAccounts=new HashSet<AdminAccounts>(0);
    @EmbeddedId
    private BatchNumberIccidFrom batchNumberIccidFrom;




    @Embeddable
public class BatchNumberIccidFrom implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column
    private Integer BatchNumber;
    @Column
    private String ICCIDFrom;




    @Repository
@Transactional
public class AccountStatesRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public AccountStatesRepository() {}

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<AdminAccountsStates> getAll()
        {
            Query query = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from M2M_AccountStates");
            List<AdminAccountsStates> adminAccountsStatesList = query.list();
            return adminAccountsStatesList;
        }


}




**M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range table**


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range` (
  `SIMProvisionedRangeId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BatchNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `ICCIDFrom` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `AccountId` INT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX `SIMProvisionedRangeId_UNIQUE` (`SIMProvisionedRangeId` ASC) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BatchNumber`,ICCIDFrom),
 INDEX `fk_M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range_M2M_Accounts_idx` (`AccountId` ASC) ,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range_M2M_Accounts`
    FOREIGN KEY (`AccountId`)
    REFERENCES `M2M_Accounts` (`AccountId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION  )
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


**M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range_Accounts table**


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range_Accounts` (
  `SIMProvisionedRangeId` INT NOT NULL,
  `AccountId` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_M2M_SIM_Prov_Range_Accounts_M2M_SIM_Prov_Range_idx` (`SIMProvisionedRangeId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_M2M_SIM_Prov_Range_Accounts_M2M_SIM_Prov_Range`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SIMProvisionedRangeId`)
    REFERENCES `M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range` (`SIMProvisionedRangeId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  INDEX `fk_M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range_Accounts_M2M_Accounts_idx` (`AccountId` ASC) ,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range_Accounts_M2M_Accounts`
    FOREIGN KEY (`AccountId`)
    REFERENCES `M2M_Accounts` (`AccountId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;





2015-11-10 17:24:10,032  WARN [AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (AbstractApplicationContext.java:487) - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountStatesRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.globetouch.business.entities.repositories.AccountStatesRepository.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.globetouch.config.ServletConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.globetouch.business.entities.SIMProvisionedRange from com.globetouch.business.entities.AdminAccounts has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.globetouch.business.entities.repositories.AccountStatesRepository.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.globetouch.config.ServletConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.globetouch.business.entities.SIMProvisionedRange from com.globetouch.business.entities.AdminAccounts has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.globetouch.config.ServletConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.globetouch.business.entities.SIMProvisionedRange from com.globetouch.business.entities.AdminAccounts has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.globetouch.business.entities.SIMProvisionedRange from com.globetouch.business.entities.AdminAccounts has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1340)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1153)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:733)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:668)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1639)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1393)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1784)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1868)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 38 more
2015-11-10 17:24:10,074 ERROR [ContextLoader] (ContextLoader.java:331) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountStatesRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.globetouch.business.entities.repositories.AccountStatesRepository.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.globetouch.config.ServletConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.globetouch.business.entities.SIMProvisionedRange from com.globetouch.business.entities.AdminAccounts has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.globetouch.business.entities.repositories.AccountStatesRepository.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.globetouch.config.ServletConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.globetouch.business.entities.SIMProvisionedRange from com.globetouch.business.entities.AdminAccounts has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.globetouch.config.ServletConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.globetouch.business.entities.SIMProvisionedRange from com.globetouch.business.entities.AdminAccounts has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.globetouch.business.entities.SIMProvisionedRange from com.globetouch.business.entities.AdminAccounts has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1340)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1153)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:733)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:668)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1639)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1393)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1784)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1868)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 38 more
```

SOLVED:

table1 has 1 unique column and 1 composite key.
table2 has 1 primary key.
ques: how to do mapping in hibernate, (one to many uni-direction)

solution:
within joinColumns use @JoinColumn(name = "abc",referencedColumnName="abc")

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "M2M_SIM_Provisioned_Range_Accountid_Mapping", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "Sim_prov_uid",referencedColumnName="Sim_prov_uid") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "AccountId",referencedColumnName="AccountId") })
    private Set<AdminAccounts> adminAccounts = new HashSet<AdminAccounts>();
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: @reos: I am getting exception, and I don't know why?can u pls look to the exception what is the problem.Or is there any problem with annotation?

Comment: What is the exception ? can you add  the stacktrace log ?

Comment: i have added the exception, if u scroll down,u will get it.

Comment: Using composite identifiers and mapping an association between two entities.
Encountering errors while initializing/loading the Hibernate schema.